# Why do my queries work in Microsoft Graph Explorer but not in my client app (MVC C#)?

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to learn more about **Microsoft Graph** and have made extensive use of the **Microsoft Graph Explorer** site.  I am now attempting to transfer a pair of queries from **Microsoft Graph Explorer** to an **MVC C#** app but I am receiving the following error message:

"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '' named 'My App'."

The following query works just fine in **Microsoft Graph Explorer**:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/[resourceID]/appRoleAssignedTo?$select=appRoleId,principalId,principalDisplayName,principalType,resourceId,resourceDisplayName`

The following C# equivalent throws the error:

```
var appRoleAssignedTo = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals[resourceId].AppRoleAssignedTo
            .Request()
            .Select("appRoleId,principalId,principalDisplayName,principalType,resourceId,resourceDisplayName")
            .GetAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The **Microsoft Graph Explorer** site indicates the following four permissions must be consented by the app administrator:
"Application.Read.All", "Application.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.Read.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All".

These permissions have been consented as required.

I am trying to automate these queries so that I can incorporate them into my app.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may forget to grant api permission, or setting delegate api permission but using client credential flow to call the api.

when we use `Microsoft Graph Explorer` to call graph api, it require us to sign in with the microsoft account first, then we can call the api, this means we are using `delegate api permission` to call the api.

So I want to double confirm with you that if you has a `sign in` progress before you call the api, if not, then the failure should be the expected behavior. If you don't want to sign in before calling graph api, you need to grant `application api permission` and using client credential flow like code below to call this api:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_appid";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
```

If you has a `sign in` progress before calling the api, then I suggest you to check if you've grant the api permission, if you want to give application api permission, you also need to click this button.

[image]